# Update inner.html before calling function

Tags: javascript, html, input, prompt

If user inputs a value less than 5, I want the inner.html to update and the user to be prompted again. The code is functional on its own, but I want it to do an inner.html update AND the user to be prompted again, instead of having just the prompt without the inner.html changing.

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate, the other question asks when and how reflow operations occur. But it doesn't solve the problem I have, which is to update inner.html before prompting, unless there's something I missed.

```js
players = []
function numberOfPlayers() {
    playerCount = prompt("Please enter number of players. A minimum of 5 players is required.", "5");
    if (playerCount === null) {
      return;
    }
    if (parseInt(playerCount) >= 5) {
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML =
          "There are " + playerCount + " players."; 
        namesOfPlayers(playerCount);
        } else {
      document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML =
        "Invalid. A minimum of 5 players is required. Hit the button to try again." 

          numberOfPlayers(); //I want it to update the text before calling numberOfPlayers() again 
//the prompt pops up without the text changing.
          }
    } 
function namesOfPlayers(playerCount) {
    for (i = 1; i <= playerCount; i++) {

        var playerName = prompt("Enter name of player " + i, "John Doe")
        players.push(playerName)
        }
      document.getElementById("names").innerHTML =
        "The players are " + players.toString();
    }



</script>
```

```html
<p id="intro">Click the button to begin the game.</p>

<button onclick="numberOfPlayers()">Begin</button>

<p id="names"></p>
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine to me. If you want the user to have to click the begin button again just remove the numberOfPlayers(); call from your else statement.

Comment: @Asgeirr The code is functionally okay on its own, but I want it to do an inner.html update AND the user to be prompted again, instead of having just the prompt without the inner.html changing. I want to know how to do this in case I need it for the future, not that this particularly needs it.